# toDataURL returns wrong value with a lot of "A"

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am using `toDataURL()` to get a base64 image.

So in my js I do this:

```
var canvas    = document.createElement ( 'CANVAS' );
canvas.width  = editImages.imgMgrObj.IMreal[0];
canvas.height = editImages.imgMgrObj.IMreal[1];
var context   = canvas.getContext ( '2d' );
context.drawImage ( editImages.imgMgrObj.getIMG ( ), 0, 0 );
```

And then I do an ajax POST request with: img=' + canvas.toDataURL("image/png")' as parameters in order to save the image in a database.
`editImages` is a file that makes some manipulation on the images.
`editImages.imgMgrObj.getIMG ( )` gives the link of the image.

The problem is this function gives me wrong base64 with lot of `A` in my string, like this : `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA7YAAAIWCAYAAABjkRHCAAAHxklEQVR4nO3BMQEAAADCoPVPbQZ/oAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`

<s>But this bug rarely occurs, in firefox 36 I haven't this bug, it appears only on the last version of firefox 37.0.2 and only on windows not on Linux, anyone know why??</s>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your image is not completly loaded when you call `ctx.drawImage()`.
That would be why you got all those `A`.

The solution is to call canvas functions on load of the image :

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload= function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
    var data = canvas.toDataURL();
    }
img.src="path/to/your.image";
}
```

Comment: It's ok the problem is solve, the problem was well I try to get toDataURL() before my image was load thabks so much for you help !